# I installed latest Xcode (4.3.2) which comes as package, can I delete the older versions?

Tags: xcode

According to apple,

> Xcode in the Mac App Store has been repackaged, and is now distributed as a stand-alone application.

Can I safely remove old versions of Xcode which are using **a lot** of space? They didn't get removed when I installed the latest version. If I can, what should I do? Which files should I remove or what program do I need to run to remove them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I safely remove old versions of Xcode which are using a lot of space?

Yes.

> If I can, what should I do?

Run:

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Where `<Xcode>` is usually `/Developer` but can sometimes be `~/Developer` depending on whether you installed it with sudo privileges or not.

Once you've run that script you can just move `/Developer` or `~/Developer` to the trash, you don't need it any more.

You can can get more details about uninstalling by reading the `About Xcode.pdf` document in your  directory.

If you also have a `/Developer-old` directory you can just move that to the trash.

Comment: Would this leave gcc and other things necessary for compiling ruby and stuff like that?

Comment: You need to run the new Xcode 4.2.3 and then open the Preferences pane. Click on the 'Downloads' tab and select Command Line Tools from the list. Click the 'Install' button to install them. You'll get gcc and whatnot back.

Comment: No problem. Ian's have to stick together. :)